# .qhc (apidoc/help) files for qt/qtmobility

Tags: qt, ide, qt4, qt-creator

QtCreator has this nice feature to bring up the API-doc for a class/method when pressing F1. Unfortunately in my case it just brings up an empty window stating "No documentation available". Using google i could figure out that i need to register the right .qhc file (qt help file) in QtCreator to make this feature work. Where do i find the .qhc files for a given qt or qtmobility release? Do i have to generate them myself?

Thanks!

Cheers,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in the `doc/qch` subdirectory of the Qt distribution. If you want to (re-)generate them, run `make docs`.

Comment: Thanks. Also true for qtmobility. The trick was to actually download the oiginal achives. I couldn't find the .qhc files in the packages provided by my linux distribution.